# What is cached with CORS Access-Control-Max-Age

Tags: cors, preflight

If I respond to a cors request that includes `access-control-request-method:PUT` with response header `access-control-allow-origin` matching the origin and just `access-control-allow-method:PUT` and `access-control-max-age:7200` will that be cached for 2 hours and always return only method PUT or will I be able to respond with just the specific method(s) requested if say the next request was access-control-request-method:POST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and always return only method PUT or will I be able to respond with just the specific method(s) requested if say the next request was access-control-request-method:POST?

It will not always return only `PUT`; if the next request has `access-control-request-method: POST`, then the cache will be skipped and new request will be made to your server.

That’s per the relevant requirements in the [Fetch spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) (the spec that currently defines browser behavior for the CORS protocol); specifically, browsers are required to cache preflights per-method, and to only use the cache when there’s a [“method cache match”](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-cache-match-method).

So your first request with the `PUT` method creates one preflight cache entry for `PUT` requests, with an expiration of `Access-Control-Max-Age` seconds — and any next request with a `POST` method would create a separate preflight cache entry for `POST` requests, with its own expiration of `Access-Control-Max-Age` seconds.

Comment: Since Chrome 72, the cap is now 2 hours. See: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:services/network/public/cpp/cors/preflight_result.cc;drc=49e7c0b4886cac1f3d09dc046bd528c9c811a0fa;l=31

Comment: @Sukka Thanks — based on the info in your comment, I’ve completely removed the outdated _“in Chrome it’ll be cached for only 10 minutes”_ statement that had been in the answer previously. And that’s had the effect of making your comment look like a non sequitur. So it seems like we should delete now (again with my thanks for the heads-up). But you might consider adding/moving it to be a comment on the question instead.